# How To Make All Cells Look The Same On All Devices

Tags: ios, swift, autosize, collectionview

Oki so first this is what i want it to look like:

http://i.gyazo.com/e76bf129ee7ae96ce0e2d84baba8e9a8.png

But on different screens it looks like:

http://i.gyazo.com/c756202d83c773b285e00ad161a67266.png

My cells width and height are both 188 if that means anything (This is set by collectionView) I Do want the width and height to be the same also like a square.

The Collections View layout is 'Flow'

View Mode is Scale to Fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set width of collectionview cell programatically. it will be `self.view.frame.size.width/2`.

Comment: Thank you! i feel so stupid when i read that :3. thanks alot tho!